# Is there an equivalent to vimtutor for bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I've "learned" how to use VIM using `vimtutor`, which I really liked. I think every tutorial should be like this one : "don't try to remember, practice".

I was wondering if there was an equivalent to learn bash and bash scripting ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no kind of "bashtutor". Bash and shell scripting are **way** too broad and complex to be explained by a tutorial. The best way to learn is via online documentation, books, and command manpages.

Comment: @ferdi_: ... and perhaps also by subscribing to the stackexchange tags `bash`, `shell`, `shell-script` ... You can also try yourself at scripting and learn how to use `shellcheck` which is an automated syntax error and style deviation detection program (some call it a "linting" tool).

Answer (score 1):

While not as a Unix command, you can  find an (interactive) tutorial for bash, and not only at http://www.learnshell.org

It goes over several topics and has an interactive shell to practice shell/python and other programming topics.

Comment: there is also https://cmdchallenge.com